# Dynamic Namespace Switching

Tags: c#, inheritance, dynamic, namespaces

I'm attempting to put a web service wrapper around several third-party web services. For the sake of this question, we'll work with two of them:

1. OrderService
2. AddressService

Both of these services have the same object defined in different namespaces:

1. OrderService.AuthenticationParameters
2. AddressService.AuthenticationParameters

I was hoping to be able to create a single base class that would be able to detect/switch between namespaces. For example:

```
public abstract class BaseLogic
{
    internal BaseLogic()
    {
        /* Initialize authParams */

        //Switch out / detect namespace here
        this.authParams = new OrderService.AuthenticationParameters();
        this.authParams.accountName = "[MyAccountName]";
        this.authParams.userName = "[MyUserName]";
        this.authParams.password = "[MyPassword]";
    }
}
```

I've seen several similar questions. Either they don't apply to my situation, or I'm incapable of understanding them.

**Question:** Is what I'm trying to achieve possible? If it's possible, am I over complicating things?

**Additional Info:** Eventally, there will be more than two services that share this common object. The vendor provides a separate service URL for each branch of functionality they provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few solutions to this.

- Have your service proxy classes implement your own interface to expose the methods, and then simply use reflection to build a type.
- Wrap both services in another class that exposes the methods and has a reference to *both* services, then simply provide a switching argument to determine which to use.
- Abstract the use of a service via your own interface and have classes coded against each service explicitly (see below).

Or if you want to play with dynamic and duck typing, this seemed to work:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication42
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type t1 = Type.GetType("ProviderOne.AuthService");

            dynamic service = Activator.CreateInstance(t1);

            Console.WriteLine(service.GetUsername());

            Type t2 = Type.GetType("ProviderTwo.AuthService");

            service = Activator.CreateInstance(t2);
            Console.WriteLine(service.GetUsername());

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}

namespace ProviderOne
{
    public class AuthService
    {
        public string GetUsername()
        {
            return "Adam";
        }
    }
}

namespace ProviderTwo
{
    public class AuthService
    {
        public string GetUsername()
        {
            return "Houldsworth";
        }
    }
}
```

Bear in mind they all hinge on both services having the same signature.

As for the other services in future, it really depends.  I've never really encountered a need to dynamically switch from one service to another to get slightly different behaviour in achieving the same thing.

Perhaps this should be driven from your app's side?  Instead of a service being chosen to suit, simply implement two versions of the class that has this changing behaviour - put a common interface on it, and decide which of ***your*** classes to use at runtime.  The class itself will then be coded directly against *one* of the services.

```
interface IGetUsername
{
    string GetUsername();
}

class UsernameViaProviderOne : IGetUsername
{
    public string GetUsername()
    {
        return new ProviderOne.AuthService().GetUsername();
    }
}

class UsernameViaProviderTwo : IGetUsername
{
    public string GetUsername()
    {
        return new ProviderTwo.AuthService().GetUsername();
    }
}
```

Then the decision is firmly in your client code and removes the need for reflection/dynamic typing:

```
IGetUsername usernameProvider = null;

if (UseProviderOne)
    usernameProvider = new UsernameViaProviderOne();

...
```

To labour the point, you could always get very SOA and create yet another service that your app talks to that aggregates the other two services.  Then at least your *client* code doesn't see the huge number of different services and talks to just one.

Comment: Great answer, great detail. I went the `dynamic` method because it seemed like the least amount of work at the moment. Seems to be working well.

Comment: @JamesHill No problem.  Just be careful with `dynamic` and remember that simple errors usually caught by the compiler may now not be found until runtime by the DLR.

Comment: There is a problem though when the return type of the methods and properties is of a class defined within that namespace.  This method would work fine if all you ever did was return generic types.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, the only thing i can think of is to use reflection to create the object. The problem is that you have to use reflection again to set the properties, call methods etc., because i guess you don't have a shared interface. While its a lot of work and it might decrease the performance, it does the trick.
 Have a look at the [Activator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.aspx) with [CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4.aspx) you can pass a full qualified class name and create your instance.
Then, using the Type of this new created object you can search for the properties you want to modify.

Comment: If class object are the same we can use: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

Answer (score -2):

You may use #if.

```
#if true
using MyService.X;
using x=MyService.A;
#endif
#if false
using MyService2.X;
using x=MyService.B;
#endif
```

But you can not change in on run time as it works on compile time.

**Note: Not a good programming practice. But this exists.**

Comment: This is not Dynamic Namespace Switching