# Dynamically change namespace in C#

Tags: c#, namespaces

I want to do something like this. If DEBUG is defined then the namespace is Test, or the namespace is TestB. See the sample code bellow. Can I do that or you have better ideas to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

```
# if DEBUG
     [SomekindofAttribute(Namespace = "Test")]
 #endif
namespace TestB
 {

     public class Program
     {}
 }
```

Comment: You might get some idea from [Dynamic Namespace Switching](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8008989/3796048)

Comment: Thanks, I think I've got the right answer bellow. But thank you all the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not adding condition into the namespace declaration itself?
If I understand your question correctly, then you can use code below.

```
#if DEBUG
namespace Test
#else
namespace TestB
#endif
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new Program().GetType().FullName);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Please confirm is this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
#if DEBUG
namespace TestB
#else
namespace Test
#endif
{
    public class Program { }
}
```

Though this looks like a *very* bad idea. Everything using `Program` would have to do the same preprocessor directives for their `using` declarations, too.

Comment: Aha, I hadn't thought that the code can be wrote like this.  Thanks a lot for your quick response.