# how can we write namespace as a Dynamic Namespace

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

how we can write Web Service namespace as a dynamic namespace??

[WebService(Namespace = "http://mycompany.com/MyAppsWebService")]

E.g. How we concatenate File path with above url Like

```
 [WebService(Namespace = "http://mycompany.com" + filepath + "/MyAppsWebService")]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40414413/12699044  ,Or I didn't get you

Comment: Seems like XY problem, why you need this?

Comment: Maybe just use reflection to get that attribute value, then add that filepath and resolve it in other place in code?

Comment: This link may help you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008902/dynamic-namespace-switching