# Is it possible to make a dynamic name space in C#?

Tags: namespaces

I want to know if it's possible to write a dynamic namespace in C#.
For example, here is a general namespace:

```
namespace APP.Menu.Setting.xxx
```

I want to make "xxx" to be variable according to some kind of assignment, like

```
namespace APP.Menu.Setting.a (if xxx is assigned to be "a")
namespace APP.Menu.Setting.b (if xxx is assigned to be "b")
```

I'm not sure this special request is reasonable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic Namespace Switching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008902/dynamic-namespace-switching)

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the same problem with mine