# call same method that exists in multiple namespaces

Tags: c#

this code works for me but there must be a better way to accomplish the same thing.  The method Search exists in multiple namespaces.  the correct namespace to use depends on code that is irrelevant just like some of the other code displayed.  any thoughts on rewritting this better?

example namespaces used

- MTG.Sites.Test1
- MTG.Sites.Test2

  ```
   static public async Task<List<Card>> Search(string sNamespace)
   {
       List<Card> rawCards = null;

       try
       {
           Type t = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType($"MTG.Sites.{sNamespace}");
           if (t != null)
           {
               dynamic classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(t);

               rawCards = await classInstance.Search(httpClient);
           }
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
           log.Error(ex);
       }

       return rawCards;
   }
  ```

the code i want to improve is the use of Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("");

Comment: the method has a different implementation for each namespace that it resides in.  the parameters for that method are not.

Comment: Can't you just write `MTG.Sites.Test1.Search()` and `MTG.Sites.Test2.Search()` directly in your code?

Comment: @Progman nope, the namespace to use is passed in via the Job object method parameter

Comment: Can you provide the method to call as a `Func<HttpClient, Job, Task<List<Card>>>` property in the `Job` class instead?

Comment: hmm, a function property?  interesting approach, but i am not sure how i would implement that

Comment: similar to this? https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/delegates-action-vs-func-vs-predicate2/

Comment: You might want to check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624731/what-is-func-how-and-when-is-it-used

Comment: i am familiar with Func & Action.  i cannot see how that could work

Comment: similar question to mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008902/dynamic-namespace-switching

Answer (score 0):

the short answer is to use AutoFac.  the longer answer is a complete rewrite of how the code is used.  i essentially need to register each Search class that exists in each Namespace that contains one. then using the AutoFac examples (AttributeMetadataExample & AspNetCoreExample), i was able to eliminate the need for reflection to find the Search method in each Namespace (passed as a string to GetType)